# DataCell's height is not adjusted automatically based on content Text height in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datatable

I use `DataTable` in Flutter.

DataCell has long Text and cell's height is not adjusted.

DataTable is positioned in SingleScrollView.

So I do many things..

I used `Wrap` outside Text, give `softWrap: true` to Text,

And I also gave `minHeight: double.infinity` to DataTable..etc

But nothing resolves my issue.

```
   DataCell(
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: rowData.secret
                                              ? Text(
                                                  "비밀 글",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              : rowData.todayDiary.length > 20
                                                  ? Text(
                                                      description,
                                                      textAlign:
                                                          TextAlign.start,
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: Sizes.size13,
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                  : Text(
                                                      rowData.todayDiary,
                                                      textAlign:
                                                          TextAlign.start,
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: Sizes.size13,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            expandUpdate = true;
                                            if (isExpanded) {
                                              expandMap.remove(index);
                                            } else {
                                              expandMap[index] = true;
                                            }
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
```

Only when I use Wrap widget outside of Text it shows all Text unless hiding it.

However height itself of DataCell is not expanded at all.

Since I use SingleScrollView, I can't calculate height manually by `MediaQuery`

Please help me..

**my full data table code** is below

```
 Center(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: size.width - 400,
                        child: LayoutBuilder(
                          builder: (context, constraints) {
                            final totalWidth = constraints.maxWidth - 360;
                            final dateWidth = totalWidth * 0.2;
                            final diaryWidth = totalWidth * 0.5;
                            final moodWidth = totalWidth * 0.2;
                            final secretWidth = totalWidth * 0.1;
                            return DataTable(
                              columns: [
                                DataColumn(
                                  label: SizedBox(
                                    width: dateWidth,
                                    child: const Text(
                                      "날짜",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataColumn(
                                  label: SizedBox(
                                    width: diaryWidth,
                                    child: const Text(
                                      "일기",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataColumn(
                                  label: SizedBox(
                                    width: moodWidth,
                                    child: const Text(
                                      "감정",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataColumn(
                                  label: SizedBox(
                                    width: secretWidth,
                                    child: const Text(
                                      "비밀",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                              rows: List.generate(
                                diaryModelList.length,
                                (index) {
                                  final rowData = diaryModelList[index];
                                  final isExpanded =
                                      expandMap.containsKey(index) &&
                                          expandMap[index] == true;
                                  final description = isExpanded
                                      ? rowData.todayDiary
                                      : rowData.todayDiary.length > 21
                                          ? rowData.todayDiary.substring(0, 21)
                                          : rowData.todayDiary;
                                  return DataRow(
                                    cells: [
                                      DataCell(
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            convertTimettampToString(
                                              rowData.timestamp,
                                            ),
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: Sizes.size13,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      // DataCell(
                                      //   Align(
                                      //     alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                      //     child: Text(
                                      //       rowData.todayDiary,
                                      //       style: const TextStyle(
                                      //         fontSize: Sizes.size13,
                                      //       ),
                                      //       softWrap: true,
                                      //     ),
                                      //   ),
                                      // ),
                                      DataCell(
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: rowData.secret
                                              ? Text(
                                                  "비밀 글",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              : rowData.todayDiary.length > 20
                                                  ? Text(
                                                      description,
                                                      textAlign:
                                                          TextAlign.start,
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: Sizes.size13,
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                  : Text(
                                                      rowData.todayDiary,
                                                      textAlign:
                                                          TextAlign.start,
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: Sizes.size13,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            expandUpdate = true;
                                            if (isExpanded) {
                                              expandMap.remove(index);
                                            } else {
                                              expandMap[index] = true;
                                            }
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      DataCell(
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            rowData.todayMood.description!,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: Sizes.size13,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      DataCell(
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          child: rowData.secret
                                              ? const Icon(Icons.check)
                                              : null,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Please show the DataTable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with `DataTable`, but from looking at its source code, there doesn't seem to be a way to have dynamic table row heights. Here is an excerpt from the `DataTable._buildDataCell` source (see comments):

```
label = Container(
      padding: padding,
      /// Since this Container is constrained to [effectiveDataRowMaxHeight], it cannot
      /// be dynamically sized.
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: effectiveDataRowMinHeight,
        maxHeight: effectiveDataRowMaxHeight
      ),
      alignment: numeric ? Alignment.centerRight : AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
      child: DefaultTextStyle(
        style: effectiveDataTextStyle.copyWith(
          color: placeholder ? effectiveDataTextStyle.color!.withOpacity(0.6) : null,
        ),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(child: label),
      ),
    );
```

Here is the output I was able to achieve (code below):

[image]

You might have to create your own widget to handle your scenario. I will provide you with a starting point example below.

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Your model data.
    final elements = getElements();

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),

        /// This is the list of elements. We 'shrinkWrap' it to allow the
        /// [ListView] to take up the minimum amount of space.
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: elements.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final element = elements[index];

            return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                if (index == 0) const Divider(),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    /// You can calculate or set a maximum width using
                    /// [ConstrainedBox]; I use [Expanded] for simplicity.
                    Expanded(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(element.title),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 24.0),
                    /// Flex 3 to 1 ratio for the description.
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: Expandable(
                        header: const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text("Head"),
                        ),
                        body: Text(element.description),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const Divider(),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Expandable:

```
class Expandable extends StatefulWidget {
  const Expandable({
    super.key,
    this.duration = DurationConstants.medium,
    this.curve = Curves.fastEaseInToSlowEaseOut,
    this.initiallyExpanded = true,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.margin = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.padding = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.header,
    required this.body,
  });

  final Duration duration;
  final Curve curve;

  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final EdgeInsets margin;
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  final bool initiallyExpanded;

  final Widget? header;
  final Widget body;

  @override
  State<Expandable> createState() => ExpandableState();
}

class ExpandableState extends State<Expandable>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late bool _isExpanded;

  late final AnimationController _animationController;
  late final CurvedAnimation _curvedAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: widget.duration,
    );

    _curvedAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: widget.curve,
      reverseCurve: widget.curve.flipped,
    );

    if (_isExpanded = widget.initiallyExpanded) {
      _animationController.value = 1.0;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Container(
      margin: widget.margin,
      padding: widget.padding,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: widget.backgroundColor,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
      ),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          /// Header.
          if (widget.header != null)
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: toggle,
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 56.0,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      top: .0,
                      bottom: .0,
                      left: .0,
                      right: .0,
                      child: widget.header!,
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: .0,
                      bottom: .0,
                      right: .0,
                      child: AnimatedBuilder(
                        animation: _curvedAnimation,
                        builder: (_, child) => Transform.rotate(
                          angle: _curvedAnimation.value * math.pi,
                          child: child,
                        ),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                          color: theme.colorScheme.primary,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

          /// Body.
          SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: _curvedAnimation,
            child: AnimatedSize(
              duration: DurationConstants.short,
              child: widget.body,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> expand() async {
    if (_isExpanded) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() => _isExpanded = true);
    return _animationController.forward();
  }

  Future<void> collapse() async {
    if (_isExpanded) {
      setState(() => _isExpanded = false);
      return _animationController.reverse();
    }
  }

  Future<void> toggle() {
    if (_isExpanded) {
      return collapse();
    } else {
      return expand();
    }
  }
}
```

---

Possibly helpful widgets:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanel-class.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html